# Rich text field 'Link' button displaying crammed text

Tags: page-layout

Is there any way to fix this? I added a Rich Text field to the page layout and the text is crammed and not aligned. I am not seeing any issues related to it online.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is this specific to a browser or happens across all?

Comment: Hey Swetha, I tried this on Chrome and Edge. Same is occurring on both